# What's the benefit of declaring for the loop index variable outside the loop?

Tags: c#, c++, performance, for-loop

I see this in a lot of game engine code. Is this supposed to be faster than if you were to declare it in the for loop body? Also this is followed by many other for loops, each of them using the same variable.

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<count; ++i)
{
}
```

vs

```
for(int i=0; i<count; ++i)
{
}
```

Btw I never do this myself, just curious about the idea behind it, since apart from performance I don't know why anyone would do this.

Comment: I highly doubt the assembly is any different.

Comment: chris is right. The reason for this is because some compile options don't like it being declared in the loop body. The two are the same, its just a compiler preference, etc.

Comment: You can also continue looping later if it's scoped outside the loop. Something like `int i; for(i = 0; i < count; i++) { /* do stuff */ if(arr[i].group == 2) break; } /*do stuff */ for(; i < count; i++) { /* do stuff with group 2 */ }`. Probably not the best design though.

Comment: @chris: Of course the assembly could be different, substituting one of these for the other can result in a program with a different meaning: http://liveworkspace.org/code/a67b2d82aafe2bd413bef5a744478510

Comment: @Mankarse, True. I meant it's most likely the same if `i` is only used within the loop.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first way is probably the C way, the OLD OLD C way, where the second version wasn't valid. Use the second way, scope the variables tight as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Originally, in K&R C, if you had a `for` statement such as

```
for (int i = 1; ...
```

you couldn't later in the same method (or `{}` scope) again say

```
for (int i = 1; ...
```

or you would get a "duplicate symbol" error.

So if one wanted to reuse the same loop variable then they'd declare it outside the loops.

That "feature" of C is long gone, but still, if one wants to `break` out of a loop and preserve the loop index then it's necessary to declare the loop variable outside the `for` statement:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; ...
  do stuff;
  if (something) break;
}

x = y[i];
```

Comment: In both K&R C and in C89, `for (int i = 1; ...` was a syntax error. You must be referring to early C++.

Comment: @user4815162342 - A lot of the early C compilers had pretty loose syntax.  You couldn't really treat K&R as a spec, eg, since it left so much for you to fill in.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the benefit of declaring for the loop index variable outside the loop?

In former case you can access `i` last value outside loop. Naive developers say that value will be the value of `count`. But sample this

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
   if (i == 2)
       break;

   //Loop Logic
}
```

In such case `i` will be `= 2` or `< 2` but what if count is `> 2`.

However in latter one `i` becomes out of scope as soon as loop ends

Answer (score 2):

K&R C didn't accept the second style.

One advantage of the first style is that you can access 'i' after the loop, which might be important if you're searching for a particular index.

The advantage of the second is tighter scoping, which is always a good thing. You can't get your 'i's mixed up.

Comment: Kernighan & Ritchie. Ritchie designed C (and co-designed Unix..!) Kernighan wrote a bunch of Unix utilities. Together they wrote one of the best Computer Science books ever, The C Programming Language. If only all computing books were like theirs - easy to pick up and read, and, best of all, short.

Comment: Thanks I never heard the K&R reference before, now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one compiler (an older version of MSVC) which leaked the definition of the `int i` in `for(int i = 0; i < max; ++i) { ... }` beyond the end of the loop.  The standard, meanwhile, said that its scope is limited to the `for` loop itself.  If you where compiling in multiple compilers, one of which leaked the definition, and the other of which didn't, you could easily run into problems if you redeclared the variable later in the same body of code.

So I could see someone deciding to make code that would get the same errors in both the standards-compliant, and non-standards compliant compilers, by putting the variable declaration outside of the loop.

Now, another theory is that the programmer wanted access to the value of the iteration variable after the loop ends.  Another possibility is that the team or coder thought that putting variable declaration on its own line was good style.